# Envelop is not being routed to akka cluster sharded actor while using old cinnamon-agent.jar

Tags: java, akka, sharding, akka-cluster, telemetry

I am actually posting an experience. Maybe I'll save someone's time.

### Summary:

**Sometimes Akka cluster sharded Actor will not receive any routed messages and the reason is the old cinnamon agent used (i have no idea how but i have evidence).**

### Details:

I have an Akka Java project. We have pushed the cinnamon-agent.jar (some months ago) to the codebase and one can point to it while running the app using standard JVM option:

```
-javaagent:.local/cinnamon-agent.jar
```

Some days ago I tried to activate Lightbend Telemetry by using the above option. Suddenly I realised that routing mechanism of akka cluster sharding is not working any more. The target actor and even the `ShardRegion.MessageExtractor` implementation were not being executed and message would be somehow lost without any log even in DEBUG level.

It took 2 days for me to find out its related to the cinnamon agent! But surprisingly by changing the jar file with a new one (fetched by build plugin) the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use build tool plugin to fetch a new cinnamon-agent.jar:

**Maven:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>com.lightbend.cinnamon</groupId>
            <artifactId>cinnamon-agent</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <destFileName>cinnamon-agent.jar</destFileName>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Gradle:**

```
// Add the agent to a separate configuration so it doesn't add to the normal class path
configurations {
  agent
}

dependencies {
  agent group: 'com.lightbend.cinnamon', name: 'cinnamon-agent', version: '2.15.0'
}
```

### Further info:

[Lightbend Telemetry Setup](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/setup/setup.html)

### Add agent as `javaagent` VM Option to your run:

```
java -jar -javaagent:.local/cinnamon-agent.jar your-app.jar
```