# [Akka]: Spawn an Actor at runtime with Scala Reflection and monitor its behavior using Grafana and Prometheus

Tags: scala, reflection, akka, prometheus, grafana

I set up Grafana and Prometheus in Akka to monitor the behaviour of my system.
If I spawn Actors at compile time it works and I can see them on the dashboard.

Now I'd like to compile an Actor at runtime and monitor its behaviour.
In order to achieve that, I run

```
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  // Class instance
  val actorCode = q"""
  import akka.actor._
  object HelloActor {
   def props(name : String) = Props(new HelloActor(name))
  }
class HelloActor(myName: String) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("hello from %s".format(myName))
    case _       => println("'huh?', said %s".format(myName))
  }
}
  return HelloActor.props("Jane")
"""
```

Then I compile the Actor, I get the Props and send a message to it in this way

```
  val compiledCode = toolbox.compile(actorCode)()
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("firstActorSystem")
  val myProps = compiledCode.asInstanceOf[Props]
  val helloActor = actorSystem.actorOf(myProps)
  helloActor ! "hello"
```

Everything works fine, but if I go to the Prometheus dashboard I can not see the Actor instance and the messages that have been sent.

Any tips to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I guess with current versions (Scala 2.13.8, Akka 2.6.20, Cinnamon 2.17.0, Prometheus 2.38.0, Grafana 9.1.6) the actors are displayed.

*src/main/scala/Main.scala*

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import akka.actor._

object Main extends App {
  object HelloActor {
    def props(name: String) = Props(new HelloActor(name))
  }

  class HelloActor(myName: String) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case "hello" => println("hello from %s".format(myName))
      case _ => println("'huh?', said %s".format(myName))
    }
  }

  val myProps = HelloActor.props("Jane")
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("firstActorSystem")
  val helloActor = actorSystem.actorOf(myProps)
  helloActor ! "hello"

  val rm = runtime.currentMirror
  val tb = rm.mkToolBox()

  val actorCode =
    q"""
      import akka.actor._
      object HelloActor1 {
       def props(name : String) = Props(new HelloActor1(name))
      }
      class HelloActor1(myName: String) extends Actor {
        def receive = {
          case "hello" => println("hello from %s".format(myName))
          case _       => println("'huh?', said %s".format(myName))
        }
      }
      HelloActor1.props("Jane1")
  """

  val compiledCode = tb.compile(actorCode)()
  val myProps1 = compiledCode.asInstanceOf[Props]
  val helloActor1 = actorSystem.actorOf(myProps1)
  helloActor1 ! "hello"
}
```

*src/main/resources/application.conf*

```
cinnamon.application = "telemetry"

cinnamon.akka {
  actors {
    "/user/*" {
      report-by = instance
    }
  }
}


cinnamon.prometheus {
  exporters += http-server
}
```

*project/build.properties*

```
sbt.version = 1.7.1
```

*project/plugins.sbt*

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.cinnamon" % "sbt-cinnamon" % "2.17.0")
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
    )),
    name := "telemetry",
    libraryDependencies ++=
      Seq(
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.20",
        Cinnamon.library.cinnamonAkka,
        Cinnamon.library.cinnamonPrometheus,
        Cinnamon.library.cinnamonPrometheusHttpServer,
        scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
        scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
      ),
    mainClass := Some("Main"),
  ) enablePlugins Cinnamon

run / cinnamon := true
test / cinnamon := true
```

*lightbend.sbt* (`mykey` is from https://www.lightbend.com/account/lightbend-platform/credentials)

```scala
lazy val mykey = "..."
ThisBuild / resolvers += "lightbend-commercial-mvn" at 
  s"https://repo.lightbend.com/pass/$mykey/commercial-releases"
ThisBuild / resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "lightbend-commercial-ivy", 
  url(s"https://repo.lightbend.com/pass/$mykey/commercial-releases")
)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

I downloaded Prometheus from https://prometheus.io/download/, Grafana from https://grafana.com/grafana/download (standalone binaries).

*prometheus-2.38.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml*

```
# Scrape configuration for default Cinnamon Prometheus HTTP Server on localhost
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'cinnamon'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9001']
```

I run

```
/prometheus-2.38.0.linux-amd64$ ./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml
/grafana-9.1.6/bin$ ./grafana-server
sbt clean compile run
```

(or you can run in IDE [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629463/envelop-is-not-being-routed-to-akka-cluster-sharded-actor-while-using-old-cinnam) vm option `-javaagent:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo.lightbend.com/pass/[mykey]/commercial-releases/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-agent/2.17.0/cinnamon-agent-2.17.0.jar`).

I can see Cinnamon Prometheus Http Server (datasource) metrics at http://localhost:9001/metrics (http://localhost:9001), Prometheus Server at http://localhost:9090, http://localhost:9090/metrics, Grafana at http://localhost:3000.

[image: Prometheus]

I login at Grafana (`admin:admin`), create datasource `Cinnamon Prometheus` ([How to add the Kafka Exporter as a data source to Grafana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586927/how-to-add-the-kafka-exporter-as-a-data-source-to-grafana))

[image]

(plugin `Prometheus` was already installed), enable the datasource, [import](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/dashboards/export-import/) dashboard `Akka Actors` from [here](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current//visualizations/grafana.html#download-dashboards), go to the dashboard and see

[image: Grafana]

Please notice actor `__wrapper$1$10f8024d0bba48c08a394d97fd56b2f0.__wrapper$1$10f8024d0bba48c08a394d97fd56b2f0$HelloActor1$3`. It is `HelloActor1` created by the Tolbox.

Links:

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/sandbox/prometheus-sandbox.html

https://medium.com/akka-scala/akka-monitor-your-applications-with-lightbend-telemetry-prometheus-and-grafana-dashboard-1b7353e281c1

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/visualizations/grafana.html

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-platform-guide/telemetry/prometheus-backend.html

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/plugins/prometheus/prometheus.html

https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/setup/cinnamon-agent-sbt.html